# Bootstrap Responsive Tabs with Ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a lot of tabs in my website designed with Bootstrap which I tried to make responsive using https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse (Demo here:http://tabcollapse.okendoken.com/example/example.html)

I was able to make the tabs responsive but the problem is I am loading content into the tabs using AJAX (like https://coderwall.com/p/1lnxba/load-bootstrap-tabs-dynamically) and the problem is that the entire markup of the tab changes to panel when resized to small size and id of the element is also changed.

So, how will I load the elements inside those tabs using ajax since markup is changed. I dont want to write separate code for loading for both cases.

Or is there any other better alternative to this? Or some solution which does not change markup of tabs but still is responsive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code, but can't you write to both elements after your ajax call? You can list selectors in most jQuery methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Bootstrap's Containers](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_container.asp) to hold the AJAX-loaded content.

I'm assuming your code is something like this (just the tab-pane bit), but you should update your question with at least a layout to get better responses.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
    <!-- ... Other Content ... -->
    <div id="ajaxContent" class="container">
        <!-- Where Tab 1 Content would go because it's active -->
    </div>
    <!-- ... Other Content ... -->
</div>
```

See [Bootstrap's Components page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) for a full list of classes that you can use.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My problem is the fact that since the tab markup changes I cant bind a selector for the tab to be clicked.

Comment: Ah, both the tab and panel change? I wouldn't recommend that. If you have content that is changing, you could use a CSS Class, then use JQuery to select the elements with that class and perform logic on them to do what you need. You should clarify your issue in your question though and show some code so people understand what you're doing. Show a layout and an example of what happens when you do the AJAX call.